# How do I use IN in a CAML query?

Tags: 2013, development, caml

I have a CAML query where I want to check if a field's "status" is equal to "Ordered" or "Approved".

I've located the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625761%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for `IN` in CAML but it's not very specific.

I've tried two queries, both unsuccessfully:

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""Status""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">Ordered</Value><Value Type=""Text"">Approved</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

And

```
<View><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name = "Status"/><Values><Value Type = "Approved"/><Value Type = "Ordered"/></Values></In></Where></Query></View>
```

This query works, validating the data but it's only testing against one element:

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""Status""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">Approved</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

How do I properly use `IN` in my statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one is wrong, because you can have only one `Value` child in `Eq` element.

Second one is wrong, because you put your desired values in `Type` attribute.
You've used correct syntax in first one: `<Value Type='Text'>Ordered</Value>`

So the correct query is:

```
<View><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name="Status"/><Values><Value Type="Text">Ordered</Value><Value Type="Text">Approved</Value></Values></In></Where></Query></View>
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer and especially the insight into why it was broken.